# Bad warning reference to temporary

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I have defined a `operator[](size_t)` which returns a warning on compilation.

> warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>     T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const {return (*m_dataRef)[i];}

**Note that I am using gcc 4.8.4.**

My code is shown below:

```
template <class T>
class Property<std::vector<T> >
{
public:    
    Property(std::vector<T>* dataRef);
    ~Property() {}

    // Return a const ref to make sure no one can modify the data via this function. 
    T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const {return (*m_dataRef)[i];}

protected:    
    std::vector<T> * m_dataRef;
};
```

The reference returned is not to a temporary, or is it? Any idea of what I can do to sort this out?

Comment: Why `std::vector<T> * const m_dataRef;` instead of `std::vector<T> m_dataRef;`?

Comment: You should provide a [MCVE]. This code has too many dependencies to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @François: this code wraps a data of type std::vector<T> data with property services (which detail is out of scope and which specifics are on the definition side). The data itself is not under the property's responsibility (its creation and deletion is handled outside of the property), hence **std::vector<T> * const m_dataRef**, rather than **std::vector<T> m_dataRef**.

Comment: You do know you're declaring a const pointer to a vector (so you can never change the pointer to point at a different vector) and _not_ a pointer to a const vector (which you cannot mutate) - right?

Comment: @Useless: yes this is intended, so that a Property instance can only tackle with a single data throughout its lifespan.

Comment: @François: I have simplified the code, so it has far less dependencies.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95550f95247d201c).

Comment: What compiler (name and version) are you using?

Comment: @n.m.: I am using gcc 4.8.4 with C++ 11 turned on.

Comment: Must be a bug in that version, try upgrading. It's not reproducible with later versions.

Comment: Hum, this is weird... or maybe there is an interplay wirh the surrounding framework. I need to isolate the problem and upgrade gcc. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks.